# Manage and Create Group policy in Azure Virtual Machine?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, virtual-machine, group-policy, gpo

I don't have on premises users and computers I have all my users and computers in Azure AD and I have created an Azure Virtual machine to manage my users through group policy, but when I applied a group policy its not working with users. I have also applied gpupdate /force command on relevant computer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Azure Active Directory Domain Services to join Azure virtual machines to a domain, without having to deploy domain controllers. Use Group Policy to more securely administer domain-joined virtual machines—a familiar way to apply and enforce security baselines on all of your Azure virtual machines.

Kindly check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/manage-group-policy) and see if it helps. If you have any further queries kindly let me know.

Comment: I have already created domain services all I need to do is to apply group policies to users I can deploy my device policy through Azure intune - I can see all my users in Azure VM but I didn't find my devices I think because they are not in a same Virtual network.